# Node Version Manager installation - what's "-o-" meaning?

Tags: bash, curl, nvm

Official [NVM documentation](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) states to install it in such way:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash
```

If you look at curl help, there's `-o` described as:

```
-o, --output FILE   Write to FILE instead of stdout
```

Confusing a bit, how does the NVM command works? And why the extra `-` is added?

Thanks!

Comment: The final `-` sends the output to stdout. In practice, this is the same behavior that `curl` without a `-o` flag will have.

Comment: Any idea why NVM docs wouldn't just pipe to bash then, if `-o-` is functionally the same?

Comment: What's the benefit of this? Why is such used? Sorry - I'm just being curious of what I type in command line.

Comment: Probably someone used to wget where it writes to a file unless you tell it otherwise, or trying to write code that will have intent easily understood by people used to wget rather than curl.

Comment: BTW, `-o -` with the space is a bit more conventional.

Comment: I don't mind - I got my answer. Thanks all!